# activiti create sub-process(ad-hoc process) dynamically through API

Tags: activiti

I'm having an requirement where Admin will create a task and assign that task to manager. Now manager have to divide those tasks to subtasks and assign to its employee. And manager can create "n" number of subtasks. Each subtask which manager has created should be another workflow process because subtask workflow will vary from department to department. So it should be like running process inside another process. I was looking ad-hoc subprocess in activiti 6.0-beta2 but couldnt find any API to do it.
I want something like this.

```
public void addSubtask(Task parentTask, MyTask myTask) {
    repositoryService.createDeployment()
      .addClasspathResource(myTask.getDepartmentName() + ".xml")
      .deploy();

    // Start a process instance
    String procId =  runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(myTask.getName()).getId();
    parentTask.getSubprocess().add(procId);
}
```

Is it possible to do? If yes, how?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the 'ad-hoc' workflow you need to call is unknown, I'd use a call activity that uses an expression to resolve the actual process definition that is used and make it multi instance, where the cardinality is an expression too that resolves to the 'n' in your question.